# Change an image from a template on a distant server (not local) JOOMLA 1.7

Tags: image, joomla

In Joomla 1.7 how can I locate, access and modify an image (eg:my website's header graphic) on a live remote server.

I have looked in my /images/banners/ folder and I have looked everywhere in the template manager.

I know I can do it in localhost because i have access to the folders but I need to do it on a remote server(the site is already online).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try right click on the header image, click view image, on the url box u will se the route for the image. Search with ftp and replace.

Usually the images for the templates are stored in the templates/images folder.